# OpenOffice Calc chart not showing my datapoints?

Tags: charts, scatter, calc

OK, I have searched for an answer to this for ages, so please don't give me minus points :)

I want to make a simple XY scatter graph in OpenOffice Calc, however when I have selected the X and Y columns and chosen the XY scatter, no data points show up in the graph.

My sheet has like 400 rows with the A column, X axis, containing numbers between 1 and 400, in order, and the B column, Y axis, with values between -2 and +2 not in order. This is driving me crazy!

I have made sure that the min. is not 0 but -5, so that cannot be it.

Anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem -- Check the data you're using for the chart.

If you've done a cut-and-paste, you may have brought in some non-numeric characters.

First look at the numbers.  They should automatically line up on the right side of the cell, unless you've changed the alignment.

Next, click a cell and look at the value displayed in the formula bar.  Remove spaces or other non-numeric characters and hit enter.

Repeat for all cells in the data series.

Comment: Crazy.  This apostrophe character was being added when I imported CSV where each column was a number.  Why would I ever want to treat numbers as text? Talk about violating the Principle of Least Surprise